# How to conditionally force fail a query in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

How do I force a query to actually fail in Kusto depending on certain condition? Ideally the exact I need to force failure is the query returns 0 count.

`MyTable | count | where Count==0`   ... the query should fail

I am looking for actual technical failure and not just nulls etc. Basically if a certain query returns 0 count , I want the query to fail so that the corresponding Web API call will also get appropriate failure return code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if assert() function helps your scenario?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/assert-function

```
let Count = toscalar(
range x from 1 to 1 step 1 | count
);
print assert(Count != 0, "Count must be non-zero")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not failing the query. It printed 1 and not the error message(the second argument). And also when I checked the QueryStatus tab of  Kusto Explorer, it shows that query completed successfully.

Comment: Ok I figured out, your code is correct, the only issue is that you provided positive condition as the argument, as per the documentation it should be false condition. If I do that, it works. Thanks.